# RNN (LSTM) that uses up to the nth time step

Tags: deep-learning, neural-network, lstm, recurrent-neural-network

Usually in a RNN only the previous input and hidden state is used to calculate the output.
However, what would happen if we use up to n previous steps? In essence feeding an n-gram to the neural network?
Since n-grams are generally quite good in short text generation, this added information will lessen the burden in the hidden state to memorize short term knowledge and focus on the context aspect of the text.

This seems quite a simple thing but I'm unable to find any paper that have implemented this.

Comment: i haven't seen RNN memorising n-previous time steps, even LSTM remembers only the right previous one

Comment: I would not pose as memorizing. We are just feeding a n-gram to the RNN instead of a 1-gram as usually is done.

Comment: maybe use `LSTM(units=n, ...` for the n-gram, n hidden states to learn sequence of length n

Comment: @datdinhquoc, LSTM don't remember only the last steps. The gated unit and the memory cell allow information to flow across several time steps.

Answer (score 1):

The closest think I've seen to what your are describing is attention mechanism in auto encoder. Where a Dense layer essentially control which of the encoded hidden states should be used by the decoding layer, instead of relying solely on the last hidden state.

here is the [paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1409.0473.pdf) if you want to read more.

This architecture intent at circumventing the limit on how much information can be stored in one hidden state over long sequence.

Comment: I've seen this paper. Basically you have a context that depends on the previous hidden states. But you only feed the previous token to the RNN. I wonder if given the previous n-gram would make the hidden state more meaningful since, normally, n-gram models are quite on par with low capacity lstm or early trained ones.